# How to rewrite angular2 formArray for AOT build

Tags: angular, aot, formarray

I am trying to compile my code for aot build but I am having difficulty with my formArray looping its controls

```
 <div formArrayName="energyTips">
            <h3>Energy Saving Tips</h3>
            <div *ngFor="let energyTip of energyTips.controls; index as i" class="panel panel-default">
                <md-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="80px">
                    <md-grid-tile colspan="12">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <input mdInput placeholder="Energy Tip" [formControlName]="i" type="text" required>
                            <md-error *ngIf="energyTips.at(i).hasError('required')">Please fill the energy saving tip details before adding another one</md-error>
                        </md-input-container>
                        <button *ngIf="i == (energyTips.controls.length - 1 )" class="circle-buttons" md-fab (click)="addEnergyTip($event,energyTip)" color="primary" [disabled]="energyTips.at(i).hasError('required')"><md-icon>add</md-icon></button><span *ngIf="addGreenScreenForm.controls.energyTips.controls.length > 1"><button class="circle-buttons" md-fab (click)="removeEnergyTip(i)" color="primary"><md-icon>remove</md-icon></button></span>
                    </md-grid-tile>
                </md-grid-list>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am not sure on how I could rewrite the parts like 
`controls.length` and `energyTips.controls` into aot compatible code.

Answer (score 0):

Some but not limited AOT Tips:

- Do not access properties by key (controls/errors). Instead access
  them by method access with get(), hasError().
- Put your controls in a function/properties in your class and what you
  need i.e.

```js
get energyTipsLength() {
    return this.energyTips.controls.length;
}
```